# jQuery vertical dropdown menu easing

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, easing

I have made a vertical dropdown menu(width 100%)

And when the mouse cursor hover on the Red Section,

Sub menu(width 100%) has to be shown like drop down... (Gray BG Section)

but it doesn't work and I can't figure it out what is wrong ....

Can anyone can help me please?

Here is demo...

http://fiddle.jshell.net/B3tZj/

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $("#gnbMenu").hover(
      function () {$('#subWrap').animate({height: "show"}, 300, "easeInOutCubic");}, 
      function () {$('#subWrap').hide();}
    );
});
```

> **Error:** Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'easeInOutCubic'

Comment: What doesn't work? What effect are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You animation is throwing a error with [**easing**](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) `easInOutCubic`.

Use this:

```
function () {$('#subWrap').animate({height:"show",easing:"easeInOutCubic"}, 300)},
```

instead of:

```
function () {$('#subWrap').animate({height: "show"}, 300, "easeInOutCubic");},
```

**Demo [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/B3tZj/2/)** *(your code corrected)*

You could use [**.slideUp()**](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) / [**.slideDown()**](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/):

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#gnbMenu").hover(
      function () {$('#subWrap').slideDown();}, 
      function () {$('#subWrap').slideUp();}
    );   
});
```

**Demo [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/uP63m/)** *(suggestion with slideup/slidedown)*

**EDIT:**

Sugeestion to you question on comments:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#gnbMenu").on('mouseenter', function () {
        $('#subWrap').slideDown();
    });
    $("#subWrap").on('mouseleave', function () {
        $('#subWrap').slideUp();
    });
});
```

**Demo [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/PpxBD/)**

> **NOTICE:** This demo uses **.on()**, which need jQuery 1.7+

Comment: oh i forgot to ask this question...how do i keep the sub menu to be shown when the cursor on the sub menu layer ? Do i have to change the html structure ?